# Confidence when sampling from a bag of two types of marbles with unknown ratio

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval

I have a bag and in it are two colors of marbles; red ($r$) and green ($g$). The population is very large $>10^{30}$. I would like to know with some level of confidence if there are more red marbles in the bag than green marbles by drawing a sample of $n$ marbles out. Obviously $P(g)=\dfrac{n_{green}}{n_{drawn}}$ and $P(r)=1-P(g)$.

I want to determine the confidence that there are more red marbles than green.

I think this is might be a null-hypothesis question in that I can test the hypothesis that $P(r)>P(g)$ but I am a bit out of practice in probability and statistics.

For example if I draw $20$ marbles and $17$ are red, then I'd be confident $P(r)>P(g)$. However, with $100$ draws giving $55$ red, I might be less confident---even though I've had more draws.

Comment: Posting here is perfectly reasonable.  You might also want to try stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Maybe check [this out](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Studentst-Distribution.html).

Comment: With such a huge population there is likely no important difference between sampling with and without replacement. For $n \ge 20,$ as the Question suggests, a normal approximation to binomial would be the easiest to compute. // You want to test $H_0: p = 1/2$ vs. $H_1: p > 1/2.$ With $n$ draws the approximate null distribution of $X =$ nr. red is $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu_0 = n/2,\, \sigma_0=\sqrt{n/4}).$ Find $Z = \frac{X - \mu_0}{\sigma_0}.$ Reject $H_0$ at 5% level of significance if $Z > 1.645.$ // In your 1st example ($X=17$ in $n=20),$ Reject; in 2nd do not reject.

Comment: @BruceET Thanks. Can you make this into an answer as I think it is the solution I'm looking for. I assume the same could be achieved using the Binomial Test, but because of sufficient samples approximating a normal distribution is faster/easier. Also isn't 5% confidence Z=1.96?

Comment: @JosephEck thanks for prettying up the question.

Comment: You're right about using binomial for smaller $n.$ // My goal was to give what you need. Maybe make Comment a formal Answer if you need clarification or something additional. If so, pls specify. // Exact p-value for 17 in 20 is P(X \ge 10) given in R where `pbinom` is a binomial CDF: `1 - pbinom(16, 20, .5)`, which returns 0.001288414 < .05 Rej.// For 55 in 100: `1 - pbinom(54, 100, .5)` returns 0.1841008 > .05 can;t Rej @ 5% level.// 1.96 would be for 2-sided alternative $H_1: p \ne 1/2;$ 1.645 cuts 5% from _upper tail_ of std norm dist'n.

Comment: @BruceET Thankyou. If you can submit an answer as per your comment I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

The null hypothesis (null = no difference) is that there is no significant difference in the proportion of red to green marbles. The alternate hypothesis is that there are more red than green.

The larger the sample, the more powerful the test and the less chance there is of making an error. For a given population parameter, a larger sample is always better. The likelihood of drawing $17$ out of $20$ and then $55$ out of $100$ for a given single population proportion is small but even so, the result of a one proportion Z test is.....................  $P(g1) = .0009$ for $17$ out of $20$ and $P(g2) = .1587$ for $55$ out of $100$ maybe suggesting they are different populations.

At the 95% confidence level, you would reject the null hypothesis in the first instance and fail to reject it in the second.